# Add multiple DataBindings to Winforms label

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I am displaying different values in a `Label` control from a `BindingSource` that is bound to a `DataGridView` depending on which row is selected.

Right now, the label has a databinding that looks as follows:

```
this.label9.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", this.bev_BindingSource, "countryRegion", true));
```

which successfully displays the value of the `countryRegion` column.

Is is possible to set the databinding as a concatenated result from two columns, in this case `countryRegion` and `country`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to use a [`MultiBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx). Add the two `Binding` instances (one for `countryRegion` and one for `country`. Then you'll need to implement an [`IMultiValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx) that will accept the values produced by the two binding objects and convert them into a single value.

The binding setup would look something like this:

```
var multiBinding = new MultiBinding();
multiBinding.Bindings.Add(new Binding("Text", this.bev_BindingSource, "countryRegion", true));
multiBinding.Bindings.Add(new Binding("Text", this.bev_BindingSource, "country", true));
multiBinding.Converter = new MyMultiValueConverter();

this.label9.DataBindings.Add(multiBinding);
```

And the converter implementation would look something like:

```
public class MyMultiValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // perform your conversion here and return the final value
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could create a computed property and bind to it. For example, create a Location property that returns the value, and bind to it

```
public class MyData
{
    public string CountryRegion {get;set;}
    public string Country {get; set;}

    public string Location
    get()
    { 
      return CountryRegion+" " + Country;
    }
}
```

Comment: I found this approach to be much simpler and easier to debug, thanks.